# Checkbox value cannot be changed based on check or unchecked using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Checkbox value is change to 1 but when unchecked then it cannot be change to 0

```js
$('.ChkBox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
    $(this).val('1');
  } else {
    $(this).val('0');
  }
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked data-plugin="switchery" data-color="#648c2c" data-size="small" value="0" class="ChkBox" name="sms[]" />
```

In the alert I always get 1.

By default value is 0 and checked. 
I want it so that when the box is unchecked I get 1, and when checked I get 0. Please tell me where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Use `if ($(this).is(':checked')) `

Comment: thanks for the help @j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$('.ChkBox').change(function() {
  if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
    $(this).val('1');
  } else {
    $(this).val('0');
  }
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked data-plugin="switchery" data-color="#648c2c" data-size="small" value="0" class="ChkBox" name="sms[]" />
```

Instead of `.attr` please use `.prop` (property)

Comment: Explaining why he should use prop instead of attr would be great.

Comment: thanks for the help. now its working

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.attr` you could put `is(':checked')` and [ternary condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

```js
$('.ChkBox').change(function() {
  $(this).val( $(this).is(':checked') ? '1' : '0' );
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked data-plugin="switchery" data-color="#648c2c" data-size="small" value="0" class="ChkBox" name="sms[]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I have just used an onclick event inside the HTML and for debugging, I have used Jquery. You can remove the Jquery, if you don't need.

```js
$(".ChkBox").on("change", function() {
var a = $(this).val();
alert(a);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" checked data-plugin="switchery" data-color="#648c2c" data-size="small" value="0" class="ChkBox" name="sms[]" onclick="$(this).attr('value', this.checked ? 1 : 0)"/>
```

hope this helps.